# Search function not working between files

Tags: c, search, linked-list, return-value, key-value

I have 2 files test2.c and comfunc.c

test2.c conatins

```
 #include "common.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
     printf("HELLO");

    int n, i,po;
    char *process=NULL;//stores the host ip to be connected


    char *ip = NULL,*port=NULL;//port to connect to
    char *pch=NULL;

    ip = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    pch = malloc(50 *sizeof(char));
    port = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    process = malloc(5 * sizeof(char)); 


    //int n;    
    char str[650];

    //int i = 0, ret = 0;
        struct data_struct *ptr = NULL;

    ptr = openFile("server.cfg", O_RDONLY);


    ptr = search_in_list("clientip", NULL); 
    if ( ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nClientIp:%s\n",ptr->val);
        ip =  ptr->val;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can't Find ClientIp to connect\n");
        exit(0);
    }   

    ptr = search_in_list("Port", NULL); 
    if ( ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nPort:%s\n",ptr->val);
        port =  ptr->val;
        //convert the port no to required format.
        po = atoi(port);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can't Find Port to connect\n");
        exit(0);

    }


        ptr = search_in_list("process", NULL);  
    if ( ptr != NULL)
    { 
        printf("\nprocess:%s\n",ptr->val);
        process =  ptr->val;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can't Find Process to create\n");
        exit(0);

    }


return 0;
};
```

---

And comfunc.c contains

```
  struct data_struct* search_in_list(char *val, struct data_struct **prev)
{

    char *dat=NULL;
    char *dat2=NULL;
    struct data_struct *ptr = head;
    struct data_struct *tmp = NULL;
    bool found = false;


    while(ptr != NULL)
    {

    printf("values of val:=%s......ptr->val:=%s\n",val,ptr->val);       
    if (strcmp(val,ptr->val) == 0)
        found = true;


        if (found)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(true == found)
    {
    ptr = ptr->next;
        if(prev)
            *prev = tmp;

        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

---

My problem is that search functions returns true values, if code of both
`adding_list` and `search_list` both are in same file.

But, if I put code of adding list in comfunc.c and 
`ptr = search_in_list("clientip", NULL)` in test2.c, search never returns true values, it returns NULL.

So question is why such strange behavior. Why this below statement is not comparing properly?

```
if (strcmp(val,ptr->val) == 0)
    found = true;
```

Comment: This code will not even come close to compiling - what is `ptr`? It's a `FILE *` sometimes and then a `struct data_struct *`. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Just try two different pointers in following two calls and see the result. {ptr = openFile("server.cfg", O_RDONLY);} and {ptr = search_in_list("clientip", NULL);}